# Office 365 AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, active-directory, office365api

So I've been working for a couple days attempting to create a working example of an application grabbing data, such as a list of the user's contacts, and display it. My attempts so far have be unsuccessful. I have followed a few guides and have read many forums but I can't seem to get them to work.

I got the feeling I have one of the following issues.

1. Either my application or I do not have the proper permissions on my employer's domain
2. I am missing a concept
3. I have a grammatical error in my code.
4. I have incorrect settings in portal.azure.com or manage.windowsazure.com for my application

As for the where my asp.net project kept breaking here is the code, look at **`var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(discServResouceId, cc, userid);`**. I got the original from here [AuthenticationHelper](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Windows-Start/blob/master/Office365StarterProject/Helpers/AuthenticationHelper.cs)

```
internal class AuthenticationHelper
{
    internal static async Task<OutlookServicesClient> EnsureOutlookServicesClientCreatedAsync(string capabilityName)
    {

        var signInUserId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        var userObjectId =
            ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signInUserId));

        try
        {
            var discClient = new DiscoveryClient(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceEndpointUri,
                async () =>
                {
                    var cid = SettingsHelper.ClientId;
                    var appkey = SettingsHelper.AppKey;
                    var discServResouceId = SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceResourceId;
                    var cc = new ClientCredential(cid, appkey);
                    var userid = new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId);
                    var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(discServResouceId, cc, userid);
                    //AcquireTokenSilentAsync is where my application throws an 
                    //AdalException with the error code "AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently"

                    return authResult.AccessToken;
                });

            var dcr = await discClient.DiscoverCapabilityAsync(capabilityName);

            return new OutlookServicesClient(dcr.ServiceEndpointUri,
                async () =>
                {
                    var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(dcr.ServiceResourceId,
                        new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId,
                            SettingsHelper.AppKey),
                        new UserIdentifier(userObjectId,
                            UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

                    return authResult.AccessToken;
                });
        }
        catch (AdalException exception)
        {
            //Handle token acquisition failure
            if (exception.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently)
            {
                Debug.Print(exception.ErrorCode);
                authContext.TokenCache.Clear();
                //throw exception;
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Microsoft.Office365.Discovery.DiscoveryFailedException ex)
        {
            Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know everything is being given to `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` correctly. For that reason I think it's a permission issue with active directory. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Was you able to resolve this issue?